# If I have 10 branch, I must give 10 branch assigned user?(jbpm5)

Tags: jbpm

If I have 10 branch, I must give 10 branch assigned user?

In fact, I will only use a branch, how to assign user at run time to the node.

**UPDATE:**

(10 branch mapping 10 different users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 10 possible branches, but each task is assigned to the same user, you still have to set the actorId of that user on each of the tasks (as we can't know whether you want them all for the same user or not).

If you don't know the actorId up front but only at runtime, you can use something like #{processVar} to dynamically fetch the value from a process variable.

Swimlanes might be useful as well here, as it will assign the tasks in a swimlane to the actor that completed the last task in that swimlane (so this might help you avoiding to specify an actor for each task, only the first).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , 10 branch mapping 10 different users,I want to get the user at runtime(listening node event?), rather than in advance allocation of 10 users. After all, I only used a branch,

Comment: @Kris ..Thanks, It is working if i use process variable as #{PVar}. But if I come to the same usertask again with loop. It is not taking the latest Process variable as actorid, it is holding the last value itself..